# Added new role with custom capability. But cannot access the page

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

Created a new role (`price_admin`) with the following code and added capabilities. The menu item appeared, but clicking it shows "you are not authorized to access this page".

```
function ui_new_role() {  
    add_role('price_admin',
            'Price Calculator Admin',
            array(
                'read' => true,
                'edit_posts' => true,
                'delete_posts' => true,
                'publish_posts' => true,
                'upload_files' => true,
            )
        );
        $roles = array('price_admin','editor','administrator');
        foreach($roles as $the_role) { 
             $role = get_role($the_role);
                 $role->add_cap( 'read' );
                 $role->add_cap( 'read_price');
                 $role->add_cap( 'edit_price' );
                 $role->add_cap( 'edit_prices' );
                 $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_prices' );
                 $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_prices' );
                 $role->add_cap( 'publish_prices' );
        }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'ui_new_role');
```

My `register_post_type` code is:

```
             register_post_type(
                    'price',
                    array(
                        'labels' => array('name' => 'Treatment Questions'),
                        'capability_type'     => array('price','prices'),
                        'map_meta_cap'        => true,
                        'public' => true,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'show_in_menu' => 'my-menu',
                        'menu_position' => 15,
                        'supports' => array('title'),
                        'taxonomies' => array('location'),
                        'has_archive' => true,
                    )
                );
```

Edit:
I use `add_menu_page`;

```
add_menu_page('My Page Title', 'Price Calculator', 'manage_options', 'my-menu', 'show_price', 'dashicons-calculator', '13');
```

This is how it looks like for my new user; (Cannot access both subpages.)
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the user in question have the `price_admin` role or the capabilities required to manage the posts in your CPT? And just a note that adding custom roles should not be done on every (admin) init, and instead, it should be done upon plugin activation or when switching to another theme.

Comment: @SallyCJ I created my new user with this custom role (I only have one custom role, so I'm sure.). I did see something weird, in the user's page in the dashboard, at the bottom there's a section called "Additional Capabilities" and it has "price_admin" written next to  Capabilities. Should this show all the capabilities added with add_cap()?

Comment: Does the error message actually use "authorized" and not "allowed" as in "you are not allowed to"? Can you show how you're adding the admin menu page (`my-menu`)? Did you use `add_menu_page()` or `add_submenu_page()`, and can you show your code?

Comment: @SallyCJ ,  The error is `Sorry, you are not authorized to access this page`. I've added more info in the question. I don't think that `add_menu_page` syntax is correct.

Comment: If the site language was English, then that "authorized" would have been "allowed". But anyway, I hope my answer helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from what I said in the comments — adding new roles should not be done on every (admin) init ([here's why](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/#comment-3194)), your code is actually good, but your post type is set to show under the custom admin menu named "Price Calculator" (see the `'show_in_menu' => 'my-menu'` in your post type arguments), so you'd want to either add the `manage_options` capability to specific users like the one in question, or *lower* the capability required to access that menu, e.g.

```php
// I changed the 3rd parameter from manage_options to edit_prices.
add_menu_page('My Page Title', 'Price Calculator', 'edit_prices', 'my-menu', 'show_price', 'dashicons-calculator', '13');
```

Comment: Wow! That worked. I thought only `register_post_type` managed the capabilities part. Spent hours trying to make it work. Thanks man!